# Loading image for jmapping ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been trying to get a loading image to show up during an ajax call using the jquery jmapping plugin to update categories on a map. I'm more of a PHP guy than a JS guy, so this is what I came up with(and all I can think of)... Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
$('#map-Shopping').click(function(){
    $('#map_canvas').empty().html('<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />');
    $('#map-side-bar').load('<?php the_permalink(); ?>?ajax=yes&map=Shopping #map-Shopping', function() {
        $('#map_canvas').jMapping('update');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

```
$('#map-Restaurants').click(function(){
    $('#loading_img').show();
    $('#map-side-bar').load('<?php the_permalink(); ?>?ajax=yes&map=Restaurants #map-Restaurants', function() {
        $('#map_canvas').jMapping('update');
        $('#loading_img').hide();
    });
});
```